# Selecting random radio button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, survey

**Objective**

I'm using Alchemer (formerly SurveyGizmo) to create a survey.
To properly route my participants I need to create a hidden question with radio buttons (single choice) in combination with a JavaScript action that selects one of the radio buttons randomly. The JavaScript should execute automatically when the page was loaded.

**What I did**

I searched stackoverflow and the internet, found a couple JSFiddles that did similar things, tried reverse engineering a solution for me, but it wont work.

I have zero education regarding programming languages, just going with the little that I think I understand from looking at other peoples work.

Using "Inspect Element", I see that my radio buttons all have the class 'sg-input sg-input-radio", so I try collecting them using getElementsByClassName, not even sure if this is the way to approach this.

Here is what I got so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = document.getElementsByClassName('sg-input sg-input-radio');
    var winnerButton;
    var numberOfButtons = array.length;

  
  function SelectRadio() {
    
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfButtons);
    
    winnerButton = array[randomNumber];
    
    winnerButton.checked = true;
   
    }
  
SelectRadio();
  
}
```

When the page loads, no radio button is selected.

I somehow feel like I'm close to having it work, but I need someone who knows what they're doing.

Cheers and thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed should work, but it require jQuery, and I don't know if it is available on the survey page. This is a solution without any dependency:

```js
function selectRandomRadioButton(radioButtons) {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * radioButtons.length);
  const element = radioButtons[index];

  element.checked = true;

  return `Selected Option ${element.value}`;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const radioButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('sg-input sg-input-radio');

  const message = selectRandomRadioButton(radioButtons);
  console.log(message);
});
```

```html
Option A:
<input type="radio" class="sg-input sg-input-radio" value="A" name="x" /> Option B:
<input type="radio" class="sg-input sg-input-radio" value="B" name="x" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! There is also a case, where I need to randomly select multiple checkboxes in a multiple-choice question. The class of the checkboxes is "sg-input sg-input-checkbox". How would I have to adjust your script to select, lets say 2, checkboxes at random?

Comment: @Juulez the code would be a bit different, you will need a function that selects N random elements (in your example 2) and check them. As it's outside of the scope of this question, I would recommend creating another question and linking it here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the getElementsByClassName may have problems with multiple classes. So I used querySelectorAll and it works.

Maybe it was a c+p error, but in your example code a ); was missing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var array = document.querySelectorAll('.sg-input.sg-input-radio');
    var winnerButton;
    var numberOfButtons = array.length;

  
  function SelectRadio() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfButtons);
    
    winnerButton = array[randomNumber];
    
    winnerButton.checked = true;
   
    }
  
    SelectRadio();
   
});
```